# PHP urldecode a string that could be encoded multiple times

Tags: php

I have a old forum script that is allowing users to inject silly javascript code because the forum script cannot not handle incoming data that is url encoded multiple times, so I am trying to figure out how to `urldecode()` incoming variables again and again until there are no more url encoded characters found in the incoming variable.

I am also trying to do the same thing for html entities, but that seems even more complicated because every time you process one html entity, the string size changes and the html entity you just decoded could be a part of another html entity that also needs to be decoded.

Anyhow... I am thinking I need to put the url decoder in a `while()` loop and keep running `urldecode()` on the variable until the variable is fully url decoded, but I am having a hard time figuring how to implement that without getting myself caught in a never ending `while()` loop.

Comment: What you ask simply is not possible in a robust manner. It contradicts how such encoding work, you _cannot_ tell from the decoded value whether it has been encoded previously, you need to know. So go and fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: The question is both too broad *and* unclear. If you posted some code, maybe we'd be better able to tell what it is we're really dealing with here.

Comment: Hi Stephanie, it's very hard to offer a definitive answer without examples, input, desired output, what you tried, what didn't work, etc. "*I have xyz, I tried this but got this and wanted this.*" If you can edit your question to include more details and specifics, the chances of getting a decent answer are much better.

Comment: I am just trying to be able to decode any type of string that may have url encoded parts and html entity parts, no matter how many times they are encoded. Example `code`https%253A&#38;&#x00023;&#120;0002F;&#38;&#x00023;&#120;0002F;www.google.com%252Furl?s%2561=t&#38;#x00026;rct=j%2538q=&#38;#x00026;esrc=s%2538source=web&#38;#x00026;cd=1%2538c%2561d=rj&#x00026;#x00061;%2538u%2561ct=8&#38;#x00026;ved=2%2561hUKEwiOi-H8vrjfAhXOneAKHWRBCAEQFjAAegQIARAB&#x00026;#x00026;url=https%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedi&#x00026;#x00061&#38;#x0003B;.org%252Fwiki%252FWater&usg=AOvV&#x00026;#97;w1ZWEB26B3eQGI5MlyG1BRe

Comment: I am just trying to be able to decode any type of string that may have url encoded parts and html entity parts, no matter how many times they are encoded. Example `https%253A&#38;&#x00023;&#120;0002F;&#38;&#x00023;&#120;0002F;www.google.com%252Furl?s%2561=t&#38;#x00026;rct=j%2538q=&#38;#x00026;esrc=s%2538source=web&#38;#x00026;cd=1%2538c%2561d=rj&#x00026;#x00061;%2538u%2561ct=8&#38;#x00026;ved=2%2561hUKEwiOi-H8vrjfAhXOneAKHWRBCAEQFjAAegQIARAB&#x00026;#x00026;url=https%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedi&#x00026;#x00061&#38;#x0003B;.org%252Fwiki%252FWater&usg=AOvV&#x00026;#97;w1ZWEB26B3eQGI5MlyG1BRe`

Comment: And the result should be...  `https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j8q=&esrc=s8source=web&cd=18cad=rja8uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOi-H8vrjfAhXOneAKHWRBCAEQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water&usg=AOvVaw1ZWEB26B3eQGI5MlyG1BRe `

Comment: To reply to... arkascha, in a perfect world, that would be the way to tackle this problem, but no matter how many times I tell a user to fix links or strings that they are copying from some other site / places, I cannot monitor every one of those instances...

Answer (score -1):

your forum script shouldn't be decoding anything, it should just properly html-encode the text when sending it back out. if we imagine that this is your current view script:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT `author`,`message` FROM messages WHERE thread_id = ".((int)$thread_id)." ORDER BY date ASC",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $message){
    echo '<div style="message"><span style="message-author">'
    .$message["author"].'</style>
    '.$message["message"].'</div>';
}
```

(and this example code is indeed wide open to javascript-injection), you'll need to add html encoding to it, which can be done like:

```
/**
 * convert any string to valid HTML, as losslessly as possible, assuming UTF-8
 *
 * @param string $str           
 * @return string
 */
function hhb_tohtml(string $str): string {
    return htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );
}
foreach($db->query("SELECT `author`,`message` FROM messages WHERE thread_id = ".((int)$thread_id)." ORDER BY date ASC",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $message){
    echo '<div style="message"><span style="message-author">'
    .hhb_tohtml($message["author"]).'</style>
    '.hhb_tohtml($message["message"]).'</div>';
}
```

- when running the output through htmlentities() (with appropriate arguments), injecting javascript to your view page should be impossible.

Comment: That is kind of what I am looking for, but it doesn't handle strings that have encoded url + html entities within encoded url + html entities an unknown (X) amount of times... As a side note, this isn't to secure anything, its just to fix display issues where a string could be encoded many times over again and again...